# Make Postgresql INDEX cover order by function expression

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have some queries like this, where some WHERE-clauses are always the same (hence I can create partial indexes based on those) and some are variable, hence I can add those to the indexes. The queries looks somewhat like this:

```
SELECT "cars"."id"
FROM "cars"
WHERE "cars"."sales_state" = 'onsale' -- fixed
  AND (cars.is_disabled IS NOT TRUE) -- fixed
  AND "cars"."id" != 1243221 -- always present but different values
  AND (cars.featuring_score IS NOT NULL) -- fixed
  AND (cars.price >= 12372) -- always present but different values
  AND (cars.price <= 18293) -- always present but different values
  AND ("cars"."body" IN ('Hatchback', -- some times present with different values
                         'Sedan')
       OR "cars"."body" IS NULL)
  AND "cars"."fuel" IN ('Benzin', -- some times present with different values
                        'Diesel')
  AND (cars.year >= 2005) -- some times present with different values
  AND (cars.year <= 2010) -- some times present with different values
  AND (cars.km >= 0) -- some times present with different values
  AND (cars.km <= 100000) -- some times present with different values
  AND (cars.images_count > 0) -- fixed
  AND "cars"."featuring_score" IS NOT NULL -- fixed
ORDER BY 
  CASE -- fixed
    WHEN cars.featuring_score < 'C' THEN 1
    WHEN cars.featuring_score = 'C' THEN 2
    WHEN cars.featuring_score > 'C' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
  END,
  CASE -- fixed
    WHEN cars.au_rating >= 3 THEN 1
    WHEN cars.au_rating = 0 THEN 2
    WHEN cars.au_rating = 2 THEN 3
    WHEN cars.au_rating = 1 THEN 4
    ELSE 6
  END
  -- Then comes a whole bunch of other ORDERING criteria which all vary
LIMIT 100;
```

I have tried adding two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX index_cars_test_1
    ON cars USING btree
    (year ASC NULLS LAST, fuel COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, price ASC NULLS LAST, km ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default
    WHERE images_count > 0 AND sales_state::text = 'onsale'::text AND is_disabled IS NOT TRUE AND featuring_score IS NOT NULL;
```

This one works somewhat fast, but not as fast as I would wish. I have been thinking about if I could incorporate the order by clause into the index too, to make it faster. I have tried the following:

```
CREATE INDEX index_cars_for_featured_carousels_v6
    ON cars USING btree
    ((
CASE
    WHEN featuring_score::text < 'C'::text THEN 1
    WHEN featuring_score::text = 'C'::text THEN 2
    WHEN featuring_score::text > 'C'::text THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END) ASC NULLS LAST, (
CASE
    WHEN au_rating >= 3 THEN 1
    WHEN au_rating = 0 THEN 2
    WHEN au_rating = 2 THEN 3
    WHEN au_rating = 1 THEN 4
    ELSE 6
END) ASC NULLS LAST, price ASC NULLS LAST, year ASC NULLS LAST, fuel COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, km ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default
    WHERE sales_state::text = 'onsale'::text AND is_disabled IS NOT TRUE AND featuring_score IS NOT NULL AND images_count > 0;
```

However that index is not being used, even if I analyzed the table first. Is it at all possible to incorporate the ordering effectively in the index or should I try something else?

I'm on PG 11 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the "year" criteria are only sometimes present, so I would probably not lead the index with that column.

But since some many of your columns are ranges or IN-lists, you might be better off with several single-column indexes (but all with the same WHERE condition) and let PostgreSQL combine them with BitmapAnd.

A multicolumn GiST index (using the btree_gist extension) over your columns with range criteria may be useful, but I am usually disappointed by them. Especially how long they take to build.

What do you with rows that don't meet `images_count > 0 AND sales_state::text = 'onsale'::text AND is_disabled IS NOT TRUE AND featuring_score IS NOT NULL` ?  Maybe you could just delete them, or archive them, or partition them away from the rest of the rows.

One heuristic you might be able to use would be to run the query with a WHERE clause containing `featuring_score < 'C' and au_rating >= 3`, with a matching index WHERE.  Then if you get less than 10 rows, throw away the result and run your original query instead.

If you can clone your database and upgrade the clone to 13BETA1, it would be interesting to see if the new incremental sorting feature would be used with your 2nd index, and if so how well it did.

An the absence of a LIMIT, how many rows would you expect this query family to return in a "typical" usage?

Seeing the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, for some typical query (both with the LIMIT and without it) couldn't hurt.

Comment: Good advice. I ended up creating a second index with `featuring_score < 'C' and au_rating >= 3` in the where clause. Then altering the code as suggested. The impact was significant!

Answer (score 1):

You must make a choice: **either** create an index that speeds up the `WHERE` conditions and then do explicit sorting, **or** create an index that supports the `ORDER BY` clause. You cannot have both (in this case).

- An index for the `WHERE` clause is good if the filters are selective, that is, exclude many rows.

  Since you say that most of the conditions are optional, the best you could come up with is

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ON cars (price)
  WHERE sales_state = 'onsale'
    AND is_disabled IS NOT TRUE
    AND featuring_score IS NOT NULL
    AND images_count > 0
    AND featuring_score IS NOT NULL;
  ```
- An index for the `ORDER BY` clause is an option if the above index does not eliminate enough rows to be useful. For that, you have to index the complete `ORDER BY` clause. But since you say that the `ORDER BY` clause can vary, that is not an option.

  With PostgreSQL v13 or better, you could try an index on the fixed parts of the `ORDER BY` clause and hope for an incremental sort, but I doubt that that will win out.